# How to tar all files in current directory using tar but without inputing names of tar file and all files?

Tags: osx, tar

System:

- macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Raw input(example):

```
.
├── f1.md
├── f2.md
├── f3.md
├── f4.txt
├── f5.csv
└── f6.doc

0 directories, 6 files
```

In a test folder, there are 6 files.

Expected output:

```
.
├── all.tar
├── f1.md
├── f2.md
├── f3.md
├── f4.txt
├── f5.csv
└── f6.doc

0 directories, 7 files
```

Trying and Problem:

```
tar -cvf all.tar f1.md f2.md f3.md f4.txt f5.csv f6.doc
```

Though I get the result from the above method but I have to inputing all file names and the compressed file name, which is inconvenient. For example , I can select all files and right click, then choose compressed option without inputing `all.tar` (I don't mind the .tar filenames.)

Hope:

command-line method without inputing specific file names.

Comment: @AFSHIN, how is that a duplicate? It looks like two completely different questions to me.

Comment: You should be able to do `tar cf file.tar .` Most `tar` implementations should be clever enough, not to include `file.tar` itself in the archive. Or you could do `tar cf file.tar ^file.tar` (with `zsh -o extendedglob`) or `!(file.tar)` with `ksh` or `zsh -o kshglob` or `bash -o extglob`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas OP doesn't want to put _destination file name_ as `target_tar_file.tar` for example, so it's not possible and duplicated as marked one, if I'm wrong @OP please edit your question to clarity the difference of yours with duplicated one. while I see OP already confirmed it's duplicated.

Comment: @AFSHIN, OK, it looks like I've misread the OP's question. Unfortunately it looks like [I cannot retract my reopen vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193061)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inputting `f1.md f2.md f3.md` you can do `*.md` or `f*.md`: `tar -cvf all.tar *.md`

For your question about `all.tar`, what should the name be? Should it be generated randomly?

Comment: I had mentioned the right click method do not need user to input tar filename but create the same tar filename every time. You can try on Mac.

Comment: I have updated details. There are many different types of files besides `.md`. So it may be not convenient using `*` .

Comment: You could use `*.*` for any file type.

Comment: The right-click option on Macs just generate a filename (mostly Archive.zip or something similar.) If you want an easy-to-use command to type, find out the command you want to use and `alias` it.
For instance, if you'd like to use `tar-all`, add this to your `.bashrc`: `alias tar-all="tar -cvf Archive.tar ./*"`. This will allow you to type `tar-all` and it'll create an `Archive.tar` which contains all the files in the current directory.